# Ошибка в коде (несущественная) c++ (дублирование вывода)

Tags: c++

Я начинающий программист ,и пытался и пытаюсь создать правильный код, который может сортировать 3 числа, но у меня при выводе появляется вместо 3, целых 6. Из за чего не понемаю.Что надо исправить, чтобы выводилось 3 числа?

```
#include <IOSTREAM>
#include <bitset>

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;
    std::cin >> a >> b >> c;
    if ((a > b) || (b > c)) std::cout << c << b << a; 
    else if ((a > c) || (c > b)) std::cout << b << " " << c << " " << a;
    else if ((b > c) || (c > a)) std::cout << a << " " << c << " " << b;
    else if ((b > a) || (a > c)) std::cout << c << " " << a << " " << b;
    else if ((c > a) || (a > b)) std::cout << b << " " << a << " " << c;
    else    ((c > b) || (b > a));std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c;
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Наверное, не *ИЛИ* (`||`), а *И* (`&&`)?

Comment: else    ((c > b) || (b > a)); <- что за точка с запятой и условие для else ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
else    ((c > b) || (b > a));std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c;
```

Это выражение компилятор разбирает как

```
else    ((c > b) || (b > a));
std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c;
```

Т.е. в ветви `else` по сути ничего не делать (вычислить выражение и выбросить), зато вывести `std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c;` в любом случае, независимо от выполнения условий...

Еще вы забыли пробелы в первом выводе.

А главное — у вас неверная логика. Попробуйте ввести числа, например, `7 5 14` и посмотрите, [что получается](https://ideone.com/2Dl8ze)... Потому что условие должно быть типа  "*если a < b И b < c, то*"; у вас же использован оператор *ИЛИ*...